# Como atribuir um valor do banco de dados à um novo objeto em C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Estou criando uma aplicação como se fosse um banco para treinar o C#, mas esbarrei em uma situação.
Tenho um banco de dados com as tabelas Contas, Clientes e TiposConta.
Na tabela TiposConta existem cadastrado o item "Poupança" com ID "1" e o item "Corrente" com o ID "2". Quando vou cadastrar uma nova conta, eu carrego os Tipos de conta em um combobox para selecionar o tipo desejado. A minha dúvida é a seguinte, como faço para que quando eu cadastrar a conta o ID do tipo de conta seja atribuído ao novo objeto "conta" criado?

Segue o código abaixo:

**Classe Conta:**

```
public class Conta
{
    [Key]
    public int numero  { get; set; }

    public double saldo { get; protected set; }
    public TipoConta tipoConta { get; set; }
    public Cliente cliente { get;  set; }


    public Conta(Cliente idCliente)
    {
        this.cliente = idCliente;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.tipoConta = tipoConta;
    }
```

**Classe TipoConta**

```
public class TipoConta
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }


    public TipoConta()
    {
    }


}
```

**Form CadastroDeContas**

```
public partial class CadastroDeContas : Form
{
    private CaixaEletronico aplicacaoPrincipal;   

    public CadastroDeContas(CaixaEletronico aplicacaoPrincipal)
    {
        this.aplicacaoPrincipal = aplicacaoPrincipal;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CadastroDeContas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (BancoContext contexto = new BancoContext())
        {
            comboTipoConta.DataSource = contexto.TiposConta.ToList();
            comboTipoConta.ValueMember = "id";
            comboTipoConta.DisplayMember = "descricao";
            comboTipoConta.Refresh();
            comboTipoConta.SelectedIndex = -1;

            //comboTipoConta.Items.Add("CORRENTE");
            //comboTipoConta.Items.Add("POUPANÇA");
        }
    }

    public void Limpar()
    {

        txtTitularNovaConta.Text = "";
        txtCpf.Text = "";
        comboTipoConta.Text = "";
    }


    public void btnCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var contexto = new BancoContext())
        {
            var tiposConta = contexto.TiposConta.ToList();
        }

        if (txtTitularNovaConta.Text != "")
        {

            //converte os textos de entrada

            string nome = txtTitularNovaConta.Text;
            string cpf = txtCpf.Text;



           if (comboTipoConta.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                //verifica se conta poupança ou corrente

                switch (comboTipoConta.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:

                        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                        Conta conta = new Conta();

                        cliente.Cpf = cpf;
                        cliente.Nome = nome;
                        conta.cliente = cliente;


                        this.aplicacaoPrincipal.AdicionaConta(cliente, conta);
                        using (var contexto = new BancoContext())
                        {
                            var tiposConta = contexto.TiposConta.ToList();
                            conta.tipoConta.id = Convert.ToInt32(comboTipoConta.ValueMember);

                            contexto.Clientes.Add(cliente);
                            contexto.Contas.Add(conta);


                            contexto.SaveChanges();
                            aplicacaoPrincipal.AdicionaConta(cliente, conta);
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("Conta " + comboTipoConta.SelectedItem + " cadastrada com Sucesso");

                        Limpar();
                        break;

                    case 1:

                        Cliente cl = new Cliente();
                        Conta c = new Conta();

                        cl.Cpf = cpf;
                        cl.Nome = nome;
                        c.cliente = cl;
                        c.tipoConta.descricao = comboTipoConta.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        c.tipoConta.id = Convert.ToInt16(comboTipoConta.ValueMember);

                        this.aplicacaoPrincipal.AdicionaConta(cl, c);
                        using (var contexto = new BancoContext())
                        {
                            contexto.Clientes.Add(cl);
                            contexto.Contas.Add(c);
                            contexto.SaveChanges();
                            aplicacaoPrincipal.AdicionaConta(cl, c);
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("Conta " + comboTipoConta.SelectedItem + " cadastrada com Sucesso");

                        Limpar();
                        break;


                }
```

Comment: O problema é que você esta pegando um objeto que já existe em seu banco de dados e ADD ele, você tem que que ADD o objeto que você realmente esta inserindo e anexar o que já existe.

Answer (score 0):

Tirando vários problemas que tem no seu código...

você pode remover essa linha:

```
comboTipoConta.ValueMember = "id";
```

e utilizar assim a atribuição:

```
conta.tipoConta = comboTipoConta.SelectedValue as TipoConta;
```

Com o ValueMember atribuído ("id"), `comboTipoConta.SelectedValue` irá retornar a Id do objeto selecionado no combo.
Sem o ValueMember atribuído, ele irá retornar o próprio objeto selecionado.

---

*Outros trechos que pode remover, pois não estão fazendo nada:*

```
    using (var contexto = new BancoContext())
    {
        var tiposConta = contexto.TiposConta.ToList();
    }
```

> Você não precisa da lista de tipos de conta na hora de gravar. Toda a lista já está no combo, e o que você precisa será o selecionado.

---

```
 if (comboTipoConta.SelectedIndex >= 0)
```

> Você não precisa verificar se há um item selecionado. Ao Preencher o combo, o primeiro item é selecionado, nesse caso nunca ira cair em uma condição `comboTipoConta.SelectedIndex < 0`

---

```
switch (comboTipoConta.SelectedIndex)
```

> Você não precisa verificar o tipo de conta para inserir. O `insert` dos dois é exatamente igual.

---

Ps.

Considerando que, não há muitas opções para os tipos de conta, é possível utilizar um `enumerable` para isso:

```
public enum TiposConta
{
    ContaCorrente,
    ContaPoupanca,
    ContaSalario
}
```

Assim, teria uma tabela a menos no banco de dados, e comparações ficam mais simples:

```
if (obj.TipoConta == TiposConta.ContaCorrente)
{
    //É uma conta Corrente
}
```

Comment: Comentário do Autor (sem pontuação para comentar, tentou editar minha resposta): Fiz as modificações sugeridas e ele atribuiu o objeto à nova conta, porém está tentando adicionar o tipo de conta como um novo objeto, então recebo um erro de Primary Key por ja existir o ID da Poupança e Corrente no banco. SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__3214EC07F7CB4935'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TiposConta'. The duplicate key value is (1). Como fazer para ele não tentar adicionar como novo objeto tipo de conta?

Comment: Quanto aos comentários sobre o restante do código, ele está bem bagunçado por eu ter começado o curso no Alura utilizando os dados das contas salvos em endereços de memória, agora que estou fazendo o curso de Entity Framework, estou remodelando o código.

Comment: A questão da diferenciação no momento de salvar as contas foi o seguinte, tenho uma classe conta corrente e conta poupança que herda de Conta, nessas classes filho existem alguns métodos de saque, transferência etc com diferenças de taxas, mas como recebi alguns erros quando fui tentar inserir, voltei um passo atrás pra tentar resolver esse problema de atribuição do tipo de conta pra depois ver o que eu poderia fazer quanto às contas filho.

Desde já, muito obrigado pelas dicas, me ajudaram bastante!!!